# Zebra Datepicker and Spry Validation - Datepicker Icon Position not Updating on Form Submit

Tags: jquery, datepicker

So, I'm using the Zebra DatePicker plugin from Stefan Gabos and it's a great plugin, I'm finding it doesn't play nice with Spry Validation - I know, Spry Validation has its issues, but still, that's what I'm using to get this to work.

So, what's happening is that when the form submits, and the validation is executed without any values, because of the error messages, it bumps the form down.  No problem.  The problem comes with the DatePicker icon not updating its position based on the parent element, or text field.  The author of the plugin suggests calling datepicker.update() which, when implemented, yields no results.

Here's my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input.datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker({
    format: 'M d, Y',                                      
    direction: true,
    disabled_dates: ['* * * 0,3,6']

});

    });
```

Here is the html:

```
<input name="specific_date" type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm sure it's a simple solution, but for the life of me, I can find anything that works or helps.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure that Spry Validation is a relevant dependency for the question? If the issue is just about Zebra Datepicker, the question could be made clearer.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution would be hide the icon:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker({"show_icon" : false});
});
```

You could then use CSS to reinstate it (i.e. reimplement the icon without using Zebra Datepicker), which removes the need to update its position at all.

```
#datepicker{ 
 background-image: url('zebra_datepicker/calendar.png'); 
 background-position:98% 50%; 
 background-repeat:no-repeat; 
 cursor: pointer; 
}
```

To me this seems the simpler design in the first place (I don't know the design rationale for why the Zebra Datepicker icon is normally positioned via JavaScript).

Comment: I actually had someone from the forum on the Zebra Datepicker website give me a solution that has been working just fine.  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Great - you should answer your own question with their recommended solution. Or link to it.

Answer (score 3):

The **[update method](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/)** described in the Zebra Datepicker documentation does seem like the right starting point. What have you tried so far? You should bind it to whichever event you want to trigger the icon re-positioning. For example, this would update the icon position whenever the browser window is resized:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var datepicker = $('#datepicker').data('Zebra_DatePicker');
  datepicker.update();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the zebra datepicker has a great user interface, but I've had problems with positioning of the calendar icon in the input box especially when the page is resized. Here's my solution

**html:**

```
<div class='dob'>Date of Birth:</div><input type='text' id='hdob' value='' /><span class="dicon"></span>
```

**javascript/jquery:**

```
$('#hdob').Zebra_DatePicker({"show_icon":false}); //plus any other parameters you need
$('.dicon').on('click', function(){$(this).prev().trigger('click'); });
```

**css:**

```
.dicon{
background: url(/img/cal.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -2.8vmin;
    margin-top: 1vmin;
    min-height: 2.2vmin;
    min-width: 2.2vmin;
}
.dob {
display:inline-block;
 margin-right:0.6%
 min-height:2.6vmin;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align:right;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The cal.png image is 32x32 pixels and the input text can be sized as required